# How to change vmnet1 ip address on Ubuntu host machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

Can anyone please tell me how to change VMNet 1 IP address in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ip link show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the VMNet 1 IP address using ifconfig itself.

```
To set IP address 192.168.200.1, enter command:
# ifconfig vmnet1 192.168.200.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
# ifconfig vmnet1
```

explained here :

[change vmnet 1 ip](http://blog.shiraj.com/2011/05/vmware-fusion-change-vmnet1-ip-address/)